# Angular 2 add/change CSS class for a short time

Tags: angular

I my angular 2 app, I have a label which shows the user current amount of points.

When the number of points is changed, I want to change the label's class for a short time, In order to make some kind of animation to let the user know something has changed.

```
<label class="label label-primary">
     {{userService.user.points}}
     </label>
```

In my service I get the user points using an observable and I can check if the number of points has changed using:

```
if (this.userData.points != data.user.points)
```

How I can change the label's class for a short time if the number of points has changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<label class="label label-primary" [class.label-animate]="pointsChanged">
 {{userService.user.points}}
 </label>
```

And on your observable:

```
if (this.userData.points != data.user.points) {
  this.pointsChanged = true;
  window.setTimeout(() => this.pointsChanged = false, 200) // the time you want 
}
```

So basically, every time the points change, just keep a flag that toggles the class.

There are other solutions, I prefer this one because its simple.

Comment: I think you'll have to wrap the `setTimeout()`'s callback with `NgZone.run()` or one of these options to update the view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually

Comment: I've just tried it locally and it worked without forcing the change detection.

Comment: @Martin, `setTimeout()` is monkey-patched by Angular's zone.  Since Joel is calling `setTimeout()` inside Angular code (hence inside Angular's zone),  when the timeout fires, change detection will be called after the callback function runs, as desired (because of the monkey-patching).